# Array with partial border

Tags: tables

I'm writing something code-like, and I'm indenting things to align vertically with paired arguments. My solution to align the text is to use nested arrays, but it might make sense to change to tabulars, as I might want to leave mathmode. My tables look something like this:

```
\begin{array}[t]{ll}
  functionName:
    & param1 \\
    & param2
\end{array}
```

Because it is very common to replace `param1` and `param2` with more function calls, and because this is a lot to type each time, I've converted this into a macro:

```
\newcommand{\nest}[3]{
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}l@{}}
    #1
    &#2\\
    &#3
  \end{array}
}
```

The `@{}` is because I want to have no extra space between cells; I'd like it to appear as though each individual line is a single string of text that is indented only at the beginning.

I would like a way to add a vertical line down from the bottom-left corner of `functionName` to the bottom of the array. I can get close to what I want by replacing `{ll}` with `{|ll}`, but that adds the border along the entire left edge, rather than skipping the first line of text.

A previous suggestion was to use `\multicolumn` to remove the border from the left edge only for the first row. If `param1` is replaced with a function call, the first table row becomes taller, but the amount of border I want to remove stays the same. Another suggestion was to determine how many columns I'll end up with, and use `\multicolumn` to have things take up the correct width. I think this suggestion was because my previous MWE was too minimal, so I've made a new example.

Here's the new example code, which includes the method of removing the border from the first row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nest}[3]{
  \begin{array}[t]{|@{}l@{}l@{}}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{#1}
    &#2\\
    &#3
  \end{array}
}

\newcommand{\AND}[2]{\nest{\wedge}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\IMPLY}[2]{\nest{\rightarrow}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\XNOR}[2]{\nest{\leftrightarrow}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[\XNOR{\IMPLY{\AND{\IMPLY{P}{Q}}{P}}{Q}}
       {\IMPLY{\AND{\neg Q}{\IMPLY{P}{Q}}}{\neg P}}\]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: borders removed from first rows]

I would like something like this:

[image: borders removed just from first line of first rows]

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Please add a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: An example including the nesting tables might also be helpful. In the mean time I guess you might be interested in using multicolumn to remove the vertical line from the first table row.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{array}[t]{|ll}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{functionName:}
    & param1 \\
    & param2 \\
    & param3
\end{array}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Edited to include a nested table, a screenshot of the output with `{@{}|ll}`, and an edit from Paint to show what I want the output to be.

Comment: Because of the nesting, removing the vertical line from the first table row is often removing too much: in the example I just added, the first table row is two rows of text, and I only want to remove the vertical line from one row of text.

Comment: There is no need for nested tabuars or arrays here, just use three columns: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}[t]{|@{}lll}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{functionName:}
    &  innerFunction:
      & paramA \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & paramB\\
    & param2 \\
    & param3
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}` With `\multicolumn{1}{l}` cou can remove the vertical line from a single cell, with `\multicolumn{1}{|l}` you can add a vertical line to a single cell.

Comment: Why do you use an `array` as opposed to a `tabular`? Currently your `array` only seems to contain text, so wouldn't a `tabular` be better suited?

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{2}{l}{param4HasAVeryLongName}`.

Comment: I edited it again to add a parameter with a long name. 3 columns won't work, as then there will be lots of wide gaps between text. I want each line of text to be uninterrupted.

As for tabular vs. array, I'm hoping to find a solution that works for both.  My actual table is full of `\forall`, `\wedge`, and `\in`, as this project was inspired by my logic class.  I wanted a short example, and I wanted the context of placement to make sense, so I went with text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106773/discussion-between-pi-fisher-and-leandriis).

Comment: Edited to add why a single array doesn't work for me. The number of columns would scale linearly with the number of function calls I have, unless the right ends of two function calls happened to align (in which case those two would together contribute only one column).  Also, if I wanted to specify exactly how wide each cell should be, I'd just do this in Excel; I'm using LaTeX so that I can automate that, and each function call is currently done by calling a macro that sets up an array for just that function. This has gotten exactly the placement I want, without the lines.